# Rounding in Ruby (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I don't know why this is so difficult, I am clearly using the wrong methods. But I am working with the Stripe API (everything works well) and I am trying to round a subscription amount to two decimal places.

For example, Stripe forces me to use cents as the unit of currency. So if I have a 995 cents subscription, I clearly want it to show up as $9.95. But the method I am using (number_with_precision (995 / 100, :precision => 2) is giving me 9.00 instead of 9.95. Then I tried the "round" method and it too gives me 9.00.

I see a few rounding posts here on StackOverflow but I can't seem to find anything that solves my convert to dollars/cents then round to 2 decimal places issue.

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to pass a correct datatype into helper.

Instead of feeding it `Integer` instance (`995 / 100` gives you integer **`9`**), pass a `Float` instance (`995 / 100.to_f`, which gives you `Float` **`9.95`**):

```
number_with_precision (995 / 100.to_f, precision: 2) # or 995 / 100.0
#=> 9.95
```

Comment: That did the job! Geez! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `995 / 100.00` (Python also has this behavior).

As you are using Integer / Integer => Integer.
Doing a Integer / Float => Float.